# iPhone - packaging multiple app in a single app

Tags: iphone, package

I would like to package multiple app in a single app. So donwloading one app and install that in an iPhone will install 3/4 apps. Something like java midlet suits having multiple Midlets in a single jar file. 
Is it possible by using multiple target or bundle, aggregate target etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. Don't do this for a few reasons:

1. I think it's a bad idea. [More on this below.]
2. It cannot be done. Multiple apps cannot be installed as a result of one application being downloaded.

Some apps act like bundles of apps, but what they really are is a bunch of mini-apps built into a larger one. I highly discourage this sort of bundling. There are a lot of apps out there that say, “51 Tools All-In-One, Only $1.99!”, but these are incredibly trashy and are bought by unsuspecting noobs with no taste. Don't contribute to that.

Comment: This something like in-house corporate app. We have 3/4 apps, so end users have to download each app separately. You know what a hassle that is. Sign the app, download, sync with iTune for each app. 
Again, for development purpose, ease of maintainance we dont want to make a combined project for all the apps. sometimes we also need the apps as standalone. So only for download and installing for the end user we need a way to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiple apps that can share data, keychain info etc there are ways to do that but leave them as separate app. It makes for a much cleaner user experience.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't make any sense on the iPhone.

You should look at [In App Purchases](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) instead.